# HTML Select option does not work after validation error in Thymeleaf SpringBoot

Tags: html, spring-boot, hibernate, validation, thymeleaf

I have a form where a user can submit his team to the web application. He can select an option and enter his name. I have validated the name field that it cannot be blank. If the user leaves the name field blank and clicks "add", the page refreshes with the error name "enter name", but the selected option cannot be opened. User can not select option again and change it. It is not possible to move on.

Using java-Spring boot - Hibernate - thymeleaf

SubmitController

```
 @GetMapping("/submit")
    public String showForm (Model model) {
        Submit submit = new Submit();
        model.addAttribute("submit", submit);
        List<String> rank = Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "X" );
        model.addAttribute("rank", rank);
        return "submit_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/submit")
    public String submitForm (@Valid @ModelAttribute("submit") Submit submit, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "submit_form";
        } else {
            submitRepo.save(submit);
            return "submit_ok";
        }
    }
```

Submit

```
@Entity
public class Submit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your team name")
    private String name;

    private String rank;
//...
```

submit_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Submit your team</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}"/>
</head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="index :: nav"></nav>

<div class="container my-5">
    <div align="center"><h1>Submit your team here! </h1></div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/submit}" th:object="${submit}" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name of your team: </label>
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" id="name">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" style="color: red">Name error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="rank" class="col-form-label">Select Team's rank: </label>
                            <select th:field="*{rank}" class="form-control" id="rank">
                                <option th:each="p : ${rank}" th:value="${p}" th:text="${p}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add team">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rank` is no longer in the model when you show the errors.

The solution is to add it again to the model:

```
 @PostMapping("/submit")
    public String submitForm (@Valid @ModelAttribute("submit") Submit submit, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> rank = Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "X" );
            model.addAttribute("rank", rank);
            return "submit_form";
        } else {
            submitRepo.save(submit);
            return "submit_ok";
        }
    }
```

Side note:

It is best to use a GET-POST-REDIRECT flow with Thymeleaf. You are already doing the GET-POST part, but when the flow in the controller is ok, it is best to use a redirect:

```
@PostMapping("/submit")
    public String submitForm (@Valid @ModelAttribute("submit") Submit submit, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> rank = Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "X" );
            model.addAttribute("rank", rank);
            return "submit_form";
        } else {
            submitRepo.save(submit);
            return "redirect:/submit";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) I had no clue that rank will not be in the model if I show the errors.